# How do I turn off the annoying peasant conversations?

Tags: the-witcher-3

The peasant conversations tend to repeat over and over, which is very annoying. Can I turn off townsfolk audio?

Comment: Pam param.. Pam pam param..

Comment: If you are on PC, I wonder if you could find the audio files for them and remove them from the game to have them hush...

Comment: Help me... I'm dying... of poverty...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to turn these conversations off. These conversations (as in many open-world games) are intended to give a bit of flavor to NPCs and different areas. As a result, running into the same NPC types repeatedly will result in hearing the same scripted lines over and over again (a la "arrow to the knee").

Answer (score 1):

Like Vemonus said they are usually added for flavor/ambiance and are often hard to turn off if at all possible in games. There are two possible solutions that might help though:

- In options, under HUD Configuration there should be an ON/OFF option for NPC Chatter which may turn them off or it may just be for subtitles (I believe it is subtitles for them unfortunately).
- The other option is turning the music volume down because that tends to just leave environmental noises playing such as leaves rustling and wind. Not sure if it removes npc chatter.

Otherwise there is not much about this online.